# Removing background image on text input focus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a textbox as below:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" class="username" id="fname">
```

And I have the corresponding CSS for it:

```
.username {
    background:#FFFFFF url(images/admin4.png) no-repeat;
    width: 256px; height: 24px
}
```

Now when user click on this textbox, I would like to remove the image, and when the the textbox is blur, the image showing back.

I've tried something like below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#fname').focus(
  function(){
    $(this).css({'url' : ''});
});
```

but the image remains there? I've tried alert in the function, both blur and focus seems to working fine but images just cant be remove?

Comment: you are probably better off removing the username class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just purely use CSS?

```
.username:focus {
    background-image: none;
}
```

jsFiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/rp5hU/

---

Alternatively (if the above doesn't work), I would try toggling a class, eg

```
.username.focus {
    background-image: none;
}
```

and the JS

```
$('#fname').on({
    'focusin': function() {
        $(this).addClass('focus');
    },
    'focusout': function() {
        $(this).removeClass('focus');
    }
});
```

To directly answer your question though, the reason it's not working is that the arguments to `.css()` should be

```
...css('backgroundImage', 'none')
```

Comment: thanks @Phil. How do you also handle not showing the background-image once the input box is populated?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#fname').focusin(
      function(){
        $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
    });

    $('#fname').focusout(
      function(){
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/admin4.png)'); 
    });

});
```