# Input background CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

I need to use this image in the input when it is not in focus, and another when it is in focus, but i cant get the images to show. Here is my code:

Thanks in advance!

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
   border:none;
   background-image: url(input_nocheck.png);
   background-size:3em;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 12em;
   left: 0em;
   margin: 30px 10px 15px 55px;

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <label for='username_input'><span id= "user_icon" class ="i-145 iconos"> </span></label>
  <input name="username_input" type="text" id="username_input" placeholder="Cuenta o Usuario" value=''>
  <label for='password_input'><span id= "pass_icon" class ="i-192 iconos"> </span></label>
  <input name="password" id="password_input" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value=''>
```

[image: This is the first image]
[image: Here is how looks now][image: This is what i want]

Comment: We need the rest of the code, the HTML and the image...

Comment: Why are you using background-size? Also, have you tried some of the solutions on these questions: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085778/removing-background-image-on-text-input-focus) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732848/make-input-field-background-image-disappear-after-text-is-inputted)?

Comment: the bg size is only a test because i want to see if the image is there.

Comment: Why not use `:focus` in your selector?

Comment: @JDeLeon92 - so, have you tried the suggestions on some of the other questions?